# How to run jquery function in background while refreshing or redirecting to another page?

Tags: jquery

I want to run jquery function which convert webm stream to mp4 stream in background while refreshing page or redirecting to another page.

Comment: Can't be done! You can't redirect and run javascript in the background. You could perhaps fake it and use the History API and load the content dynamically ?

Comment: You can use background workers to run code in the background, but only within the same page. If you refresh or redirect, you lose the background workers of that page.

Comment: This is alreay using background worker, but I want to run ib background while redirecting.